# Spring boot - 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

We encounter a problem that happens often (mostly first time) in the following architecture.
We have an app X communicating with an app Y that calls an external API. 
Sometimes the app Y calls the external API it sends back :

```
<html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>The server didn't respond in time.\n</body></html>
```

We tried to set this value in application.yml

```
server:
    connection-timeout: 300000
```

And also modifying the rest Template timeout value :

```
  private ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(600000);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(600000);
    factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(600000);
    return factory;
  }
```

The code throwing the error :

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        return restTemplate.exchange(uri, httpMethod, requestEntity, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CompletionException(e); // The exception we throw that contains the html code.
    }
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?